# How to block IP ranges with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Question regarding blocking IP ranges.

Is there any advantage to have deny from between order allow,deny and allow from all?

```
order allow,deny
deny from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
deny from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
allow from all
```

Compared to having deny from after allow from all?

```
order allow,deny
allow from all
deny from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
deny from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Is one method better than the other?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Two answers:

1) Those two blocks are *logically* identical, because it is the `order` directive, not the order in which the lines appear, that determines which order they are applied. Thus, in both cases, the allow is applied first, and then the deny, because that's what you said in the `order` directive. That said, having the directives in the order that they will be applied (allow first, then deny) is easier to read, and thus probably easier to maintain.

2) Apache httpd 2.4 has been out almost 5 years now, and has greatly simplified the way that access control (eg, IP-address based access control) is stated. No more of this confusing `order` stuff. I encourage you to have a look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html and consider moving to 2.4. 2.2 will be designated "End Of Life" fairly soon, and it's time to migrate.

Comment: Many thanks. I will look into this with my host. Appreciate the reply.